# How use 'in' query in SpringDataJpa framework

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I don't konw how to use `in query` in springdatajpa framework.

`Menu.java` has `roles` field，I want to perform an 'IN' query using the 'roles' field 。

## Code:

### Menu.java

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Table(name = "t_sys_menu")
@org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicInsert
@org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicUpdate
@org.hibernate.annotations.Where(clause = SysConstants.WHERE_DELETE)
public class Menu extends TreeEntity<Menu, Long> {

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "t_sys_role_menu", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "menu_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Collection<Role> roles;
```

### query method

```java
    private Specification<Menu> buildSearchSpecification(MenuDTO menuDTO) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
            if (StringUtils.hasText(menuDTO.getRoleIds())) {
                List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Long roleId : Convert.toList(Long.class, menuDTO.getRoleIds())) {
                    roles.add(new Role(roleId));
                }
                predicates.add(root.get(Menu_.roles).in(roles));
            }
            return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
        };
    }
```

I get this error

## Error

`Parameter value [com.appmtce.pojo.entity.role.Role@20f81e2a] did not match expected type [java.util.Collection (n/a)]`

Answer (score 0):

update code from

```java
predicates.add(root.get(Menu_.roles).in(roles));
```

to

```java
predicates.add(root.join(Menu_.roles, JoinType.LEFT).in(roles));
```